# How to grab defaultValue from a text field that has a value set by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have set a value through use of jQuery. Ultimately I want the value to clear if the textfield still says 'Year'.

It seems like defaultValue is empty if you set the value attribute through jQuery. Is there a way to set the value of a text input through JS and then retrive it through JS?

*I have this snippet executing only for IE8 and below, due to the lack of support of the HTML5 'placeholder' attribute. I can not set the 'value' attribute directly in the HTML because it throws off my 'placeholder' functionality. So i am forced to do something similar to this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bro').attr('value','Year');

    $('.bro').focus(function() {
       if (this.value == this.defaultValue){this.value = '';}
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What is the issue with the current code you have? Try `$('.bro').prop('defaultValue','Year');`

Comment: The issue was this.defaultValue was returning an empty string. But I had an idea sparked by your recommendation of using .prop('defaultValue','Year');

Comment: Thanks @PSL. How do I accept your answer/suggestion?

Comment: I would need to post that as answer. What solved ur issue. Infact u can post an answer yourself and accept it

Comment: The use of setting defaultValue through prop() is something I didnt think of until I saw your comment.

Comment: Yep, I would just copy/paste what you have in your first comment (everything after 'Try ...')

Comment: Ok. Posted as answer, if you would like to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the value for the `defaultValue` property of the element like `$('.bro').prop('defaultValue','Year');`.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $bro = $('.bro');
    $bro.prop('defaultValue','Year');

    $bro.focus(function() {
       if (this.value === this.defaultValue){this.value = '';}
    }); 
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MR57S/)**

Answer (score 0):

With lack of HTML5 you're a bit limited, I would just set a global variable to be whatever the placeholder is and go against that:

```
var defaultText = "year";
$('.bro').val(year);

$('.bro').focus(function() {
    if (this.value == defaultText) //do stuff
    else //do stuff
});
```